# what does T const & mean in return types of functions?

Tags: c++, constants

What kind of a return type does the following function prototype have?

```
int const& myfunctionname(int i)
```

I am not getting the use of the const and & here. If I am returning objects/arrays/ basically non-local variables, should I use a pointer or a reference if I want to return the location of the object?

Comment: same as: const int &...

Comment: This function returns a reference of a member variable of the class it belongs to, but the calling function will not be able to change it.

Comment: @barakmanos : So, the member variable itself can be modified inside the function, but any calling function cannot modify it ? Also, can you tell me if there is any preference in using * or & for this ?

Comment: See my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such function can return a reference to a member variable of the class it belongs to, but the calling function will not be able to change it. For example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {boo=5;}
public:
    int const& myfunctionname(int i) {boo += i; return boo;}
private:
    int boo;
}

void func(Foo& foo)
{
    const int& a = foo.myfunctionname(6);
    a += 7; // Compilation error
    int b = a+7; // OK
}
```

**Supplemental:**

The most common example of returning a constant value by reference, is probably `operator++()`.

Answer (score 2):

It means you're returning a reference to a value that cannot be changed.

If you return a reference to a local variable then you're going to have a problem, as it will reference something that no longer exists:

```
int const &GetValue()
{
 int x = 10;
 return x;  // THIS IS BAD!
}
```

Also, it doesn't really make sense to return const references to the integral types (int, long, etc) as they take pretty much the same space as the reference in the first place. However if you do then it's not a big deal.

If you're returning non-local data (ie member data) then use references if the data will always exists, and use pointers if the data may not exist, so that `NULL` indicates the absence of the data. For example:

```
const std::string &User()const
{
  return m_Username;
}

int Age() const
{
  return m_Age; // Pointless to use a reference here
}

const Person *Partner()const
{
  return m_Parter; // User may not have a partner, so pointer
}
```

Make the pointer or reference `const` if you don't want the caller to be able to modify the object returned.